# Power BI - Clustered column chart - percentage by year

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table like the following

```
Client  Rate  Year 
x        1    2018
x        2    2017
z        1    2016
f        1    2018
e        2    2016
a        4    2017
c        3    2018
```

I want to show a Clustered column chart like:
- Axis (Rate)
- Legend(Year)
- Value(% count of rating)

The goal is to have the percentage of each rate by year;
example: for 2018 (30% of note 1, 50% of note 2 and 20% of note 3) and for 2017(20% note 1, 20% note 2 and 60% note3).
Except that the percentage is by all years,  which is very small.I  want the percentage by a single year. how can i achieve this?

What i want ia a chart like this:

[image: Chart example]

Except yhat the percentage is calculated as:

Occurence of a note in a year / all the ocuurences(from all years)

Then the percentages are very low. What i want instead is the percentage calculated as:

Occurence of a note in a year / all ocuurences from the same year

Comment: I don't understand where your percentages are coming from or what the notes you mention are. Can you explain better and mock up what you want your chart to look like?

Comment: i've provided an example, i hope this will help you understand better

Answer (score 3):

You just need to write an appropriate measure to get the percentages you're after. Try something along these lines:

```
= COUNT(Table1[Client]) / CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[Client]), ALL(Table1[Rate]))
```

The `COUNT` in the numerator gives the count of clients for that rate and year combination. In the denominator, we remove the `Rate` filter context but the `Year` filter context remains.

---

Another way to approach this would be like this:

```
= COUNT(Table1[Client]) / CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[Client]), ALLEXCEPT(Table1, Table1[Year]))
```

This says that we want to remove all filter context except for `Year`.